# Drupal: how to add pdf links to a block?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I've some blocks in my Drupal website with some text.

I need to other some links in the text, to pdfs (and upload them from back-end).

Can I add some upload fields to the block pages, and link them from the text ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [Insert module](http://drupal.org/project/insert), which allows you to upload files to a FileField and then easily link to them from within the node body.

Comment: I've just installed, it seems it doesn't solve my issue with blocks

Comment: Ah, sorry about that, I somehow missed the part(s) where you said "blocks". I don't know of anything offhand to allow you to achieve this with blocks, but I'll update my answer if I think of anything.

Answer (score 0):

I usually just end up attaching them to a node and then linking them manually. Not the answer you were probably looking for, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you have views module available you can create a view that lists the pdfs attached to a particular node, using the node id (nid) as an argument, or use more complicated arguments if you want, as long as the fields displayed in the view are the the filefields you used for your pdf you can get pretty creative with how the pdfs are organized.

It's somewhat tricky to get arguments into views blocks but it's certainly possible, using panels, or using other tricks. More info on that: 
here: http://drupal.org/node/150482
here: http://drupal.org/node/695124
http://drupal.org/node/161867#comment-1086587

Answer (score 0):

Might not actually help you, but the D7 version of http://drupal.org/project/block_api creates fieldable blocks, which means that you can attach any type of fields to created blocks.

For D6, the solution is more complex I guess. You could create a separate content type, attach the files there (by using Inline, FileField, ...). Then, either write a custom module that exposes a block for each node of that type and then renders the node in those blocks or use Views to create a view of a single node. Using views would be a bit overkill I guess but should be relatively fast if you can use caching..